# Bad TCP Connection Because of Duplicate TCP SYN

Tags: ios, linux, networking, tcp

My iPhone establishes TCP connection to a linux server:

> iOS   -----tcp syn----> linux
>
> iOS   -----tcp syn----> linux
>
> linux -----tcp ack with seq=xxx --->iOS
>
> linux -----tcp ack with seq=yyy --->iOS

iOS resends TCP syn quickly, thus leads to two TCP ACK with different server seq.
iOS uses the first seq xxx, linux uses the second seq yyy. So this connection cannot transmit data.

It is a mistake that iOS resends syn so quickly, but is linux server doing the right thing? how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue happened on CentOS 5.6  x86, I moved server to CentOS 6.5 x64, this issue was resolved.

not sure whether the issue is caused by CentOS or caused by configure.

I prefer that this is issue about the CentOS 5.6, not tcp configure